# Where was a C#/.NET application looking, when it couldn't find a DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

An application always crashes with System.DllNotFoundException.  I've put the DLL, which is used through [DllImport(...)] statements, into the same folder as the application's .exe file.   I tried putting the DLL in other places, just in case. No go.    Doesn't an application always look in its own .exe's folder?

Is there some way to find out where the application thought it was looking when it couldn't find the DLL?

I do not want to read articles or documentation explaining how applications normally find DLLs.  I want to find out specifically where *this* application was actually looking when it threw that exception.  Were the paths written to a log file?

This DLL is one of our own, from a different Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see the app searching for the DLL.  Shows you what you are asking about, even though that is not your problem.  What it also shows you is the DLL that is missing.  Never the one that you are actually using, that's too obvious, another one that the DLL needs to get its job done.  Like the C runtime library, everybody always forgets that one.

Comment: dllimport grumble grumble here's twenty reps. I hope ya choke on it. Nyah.

Comment: instead of attaching the .Dll throug the Import statement unless it's an unmanaged .dll could you not just add it to the project references as well as the using and create a Lib folder that holds all your 3rd party dll's also an alternative if the `Dll` does not change would be to `GAC` that and perhaps it would be found as well

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx